# Java variables value change listener

Tags: java, variables, events, onchange

My question is how can we implement something(a listener) with the help of which we can get notified when its value is changed.

For example:

```
public class Var{
    public int value;
    public String str;

    //Here is what I want
    @ value on change
    private void valueChanged(T prev){
         System.out.print(value +" changed!");
    }
}
```

Now, this can be done by a setter method but in case that there are many of such variables it's difficult to handle all of the methods.

Mainly, I would like to know whether this is possible to be implemented or not?

Note :  It is preferable not to use a y external framework!

Comment: Utilize **Setter** methods in your class and have class instance variables as **private** instead of **public**.

Comment: @DevilsHnd i already clearly mentioned that i know of setters but i want to know whether there is an alternative!